# Problema con formato de fecha al enviar json con android retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit

Tengo un problema con android que espero puedan ayudarme. Estoy utilizando retrofit para hacer un post request de un json a una api en php. El json contiene fechas en el formato "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss" ya que se guardarán en una base de datos de mysql. Según yo y la consola de android las fechas se envían con el formato esperado pero a php están llegando con este formato: Oct 22, 2021 6:55:55 PM cuando las estoy enviando como "2021-10-22 18:55:55"
Como dato adicional usando postman hago un post con mi cadena de json y las fechas llegan correctamente. Pongo el código de mi petición de retrofit y mi pojo que serializo

````
   @Headers({
           "Accept: application/json",
           "Content-Type: application/json"
   })
   Call<PostResponse> saveInformeEnvio(@Body InformeEnvio item);


public class InformeEnvio {
   private Visita visita;
   private InformeCompra informeCompra;
   private List<InformeCompraDetalle> informeCompraDetalles;
   private List<ImagenDetalle> imagenDetalles;
   private List<ProductoExhibido> productosEx;

   public Visita getVisita() {
       return visita;
   }

   public void setVisita(Visita visita) {
       this.visita = visita;
   }

   public InformeCompra getInformeCompra() {
       return informeCompra;
   }

   public void setInformeCompra(InformeCompra informeCompra) {
       this.informeCompra = informeCompra;
   }

   public List<InformeCompraDetalle> getInformeCompraDetalles() {
       return informeCompraDetalles;
   }

   public void setInformeCompraDetalles(List<InformeCompraDetalle> informeCompraDetalles) {
       this.informeCompraDetalles = informeCompraDetalles;
   }

   public List<ImagenDetalle> getImagenDetalles() {
       return imagenDetalles;
   }

   public void setImagenDetalles(List<ImagenDetalle> imagenDetalles) {
       this.imagenDetalles = imagenDetalles;
   }

   public List<ProductoExhibido> getProductosEx() {
       return productosEx;
   }

   public void setProductosEx(List<ProductoExhibido> productosEx) {
       this.productosEx = productosEx;
   }
   public String toJson(InformeEnvio informe) {
       //  this.inf_visitasIdlocal=informe.getVisitasId();
      
       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").create();

       String informejson=gson.toJson(informe.informeCompra);
       String JSON = gson.toJson(informe);
       return  JSON;
      
     

      }
  }```


Cualquier observación será bien recibida. 
Gracias
````

Answer (score 0):

Se que ha pasado un poco de tiempo pero me contestaron en el otro stackoverflow y la comparto aquí

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70613208/android-retrofit-change-the-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-in-a-post-request